# transform class methods using parent class' decorator method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, decorator

```py
def greeting_decorator(original_function):
    def return_function(*args):
        name = 'John'
        return f'Hi, I\'m {name}, fullname: {original_function(*args)}'
    return return_function

@greeting_decorator
def greeting(name, surname):
    return f'{name} {surname}'

print(greeting('John', 'Doe'))
```

Above, I have a simple decorator function that works as intended.
I'd like to do something similar, but with an inherited class.
How might I go about inheriting a decorator function like this:

```py
class Guy:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = 'John'

    def greeting_decorator(self, original_function):
        def return_function(*args):
            return f'Hi, I\'m {self.name}, fullname: {original_function(*args)}'
        return return_function


class GuyWithSurname(Guy):

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.surname = surname

    @greeting_decorator # <----- here
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'
    
JohnDoe = GuyWithSurname('John', 'Doe')
print(JohnDoe)
```

Comment: If you always know the parent class you can do `@Guy.greeting_decorator` instead.

Comment: You have to use `Guy.greeting_decorator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain that the parent class will always be `Guy`, you can simply annotate via `@Guy.greeting_decorator`:

```py
class Guy:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = 'John'

    def greeting_decorator(original_function):
        def return_function(self, *args):
            return f'Hi, I\'m {self.name}, fullname: {original_function(self, *args)}'
        return return_function

class GuyWithSurname(Guy):

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.surname = surname

    @Guy.greeting_decorator # <----- here
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'

JohnDoe = GuyWithSurname('John', 'Doe')
```

That way, when you call `print(JohnDoe)` it will output `Hi, I'm John, fullname: John Doe`.

Note that I had to change the `greeting_decorator` and the `return_function` parameters to properly handle `self`.